# Having trouble launching discord bot, SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.io

I'm creating a small Discord bot that every time you enter `!lenny`, it will respond with a lennyface. However, I'm having trouble getting the bot started up. It's throwing a `SyntaxError` that the token is invalid. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});

logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'lenny':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: '( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pinged!'
                });
            break;
            case 'ver':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: '0.0.4'
                });
            break;
         }
     }
});
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot\auth:2
"token": "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot\bot.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
```

Ive tried changing the file paths for `var auth = require('./auth');` to `var auth = require('./auth.json');` aswell as `auth` to `auth.json`, this is the output.

```
C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot>node bot.js

C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot>
```

Edit: Ive ended up using a more recent script and it works much better. Not deleting to help others that are having a similar problem.

Comment: Do you have these `“` quotes in your actual code, or is that a copy-paste accident? Because those aren't valid, you need `"` standard ones.

Comment: What type of file is `auth`?

Comment: Used standard quotes, this is the new error output.

Comment: I also see that the problem is coming from `C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot\bot.js:3:12` so you probably using a token that is not in the correct format

Comment: @slothiful .json

Comment: Can you confirm that the file ends in `.json`? It doesn't show that it does in the stack trace, and that would be why you're now receiving an unexpected token error.

Comment: @slothiful This is the output, the bot does not start ```C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot>node bot.js

C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\LennyBot>```

Comment: Is your token defined? Do a console.log before `auth.token` (do not paste the result here, just make sure that it is the token that you expect). You need a valid token from the discord api.

Comment: The token is defined in ```auth.json``` and it is correct, ive double checked it

Comment: By token it doesn't mean the Discord client token, it means the character within the json.

Comment: Not sure im picking up what you are putting down here.